# Import form current directory in python with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, import, wsgi

I am running my python (3.4) scripts using apchae+mod_wsgi with the wsgi-script handler.

I found that this uses "/" as the execution path, so for easy file acces I do

```
os.chdir( os.path.dirname(environ['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
```

after my script starts up.
However, I noticed that for some reason python does not add the current working dir to sys.path when started this way, making it imposible to do imports from the current dir.
Appart from that I find this behaviour very wierd, since it makes development really hard, I am wondering if this can be changed. preverably without starting eacht file with a line to add the current path to sys.path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change the current working directory from within your Python code and it is generally regarded as bad practice in Python web application to assume that specific directories will be searched unless the WSGI server has been specifically setup to do so. This is because different WSGI servers behave differently due to how they need to hook into any companion web server if used.

The current working directory issues is described in the documentation at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

As far as explaining what you can do, you are though probably better off reading:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/python-module-search-path-and-modwsgi.html

If you are using an out of date mod_wsgi version then I also suggest you upgrade to use the better way of handling this as described in that blog post. Also make sure you are using daemon mode as well and not embedded mode.